# Slice final queryset return amount: Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

In the following function, I would like to return only 200 objects, whether the filter is applied or not.

Whenever I try to do this, I can an error saying: `Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.`

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Book.objects \
        .select_related('user', 'category') \
        .prefetch_related('likers') \
        .all()
    tag = self.request.query_params.get('tag', None)

    if tag is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(description__iexact='#{}'.format(tag)))
    return queryset[:200]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: do you have another filter somewhere also on this queryset?

Comment: @doniyor Nope. I do a `select_related` and `prefetch_related` call on the initial queryset, but that's it.

Comment: may be showing us the whole listview will help to debug

Comment: @doniyor I just edited the post to show the whole function

Comment: still dont see any bad code.. is it detailview? could you show the whole view may be?

Comment: Can you post traceback for that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pagination instead. Set the page size to 200 items. No matter if you don´t use other pages, the first page will be all you need.

That way you are using built-in methods to get just 200 items and you won´t get any error

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, this exception is raised when Django tries to chain any ORM function (`filter`, `exclude`, `values`...) on a queryset that have been sliced.

The snippet you shared seems correct and does return a sliced queryset. You need to check that everytime you use the result of `get_queryset`, you are simply iterating over it and not trying to use it as a `QuerySet` object.

In DRF, you can return a sliced queryset AFAIK, if you are not overriding `get_queryset` in a child class to do extra stuff with it.